# How do you merge two objects with functions into a new one using ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to join two objects with functions into a merged object using ES6, not sure how to do this.

For example, I'd like to merge these two objects:

```
const first = {
  first: function() {
    return {
      type: FIRST
    };
  }
};

const second = {
  second: function() {
    return {
      type: SECOND
    };
  }
};
```

Into a new object:

```
const new = {
  first: function() {
    return {
      type: FIRST
    };
  },
  second: function() {
      return {
      type: SECOND
    };
  }
}
```

What is the best way to do this?  I tried `Object.assign({}, first, second);` but this returned `{}`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hey Rob, that might be the cause of my issue, good catch!

Comment: Note that *new* is a [keyword](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-keywords) and can't be used as an identifier. Sorry, brain fade on *const*. See [*MDN: Object.assign*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use Object.assign for this:

Note as mentioned in Chris' answer below, this will mutate the first object.

[JSBin example](https://jsbin.com/jefogo/1/edit?js,console)

```
var joined = Object.assign(first, second);

// joined:

{
  first: function first() {
    return {
      type: FIRST
    };
  },
  second: function second() {
    return {
      type: SECOND
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I tried the Object.assign and for some reason was getting back {}, must have been a typo.

Comment: That modifies *first*, it doesn't create a new object (`joined === first`).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something...The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: to your edit, I mentioned that in the answer's second line

Answer (score 4):

Your example should indeed work:

```
var joined = Object.assign({}, first, second);
```

**Be careful** using assign without an empty object as the first parameter, such as:

```
var joined = Object.assign(first, second);
```

Because `first` will be **mutated**.

JSBin example running your own code (and working):

https://jsbin.com/tekokawice/edit?js,console

Comment: this is an excellent point, if you cannot or do not want to mutate the first object

Comment: Ya, absolutely - I guess it depends on the original authors intention - but technically both our answers could be right (depending on their requirements) :)

Comment: Agreed, thanks, I'll be adding the first parameter, I definitely don't want to mutate either object.

Comment: No worries. Possibly just a typo or something in your original snippet because it looks right